# Thread.sleep doesn't sleep on Cloudbees platform

Tags: cloudbees, thread-sleep

I'm using this simple `Thread.sleep(216000000);` //24hours on war file
I upload to the Cloudbees paas platform.
Everything is working fine, but thread isn't going to sleep.
Any idea why?

Comment: Did this same code work locally? Be aware that you app will hibernate after 2 hours, so this code doesn't make sense unless you upgrade your app to the paid tier making it works 24/7.

Comment: yes it worked locally. I will upgrade if it was working.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed on CloudBees a simple test java application with this main:

public class ThreadExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        new Thread("" + i){
            public void run(){

                if(Integer.valueOf(getName())==5){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(15000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Thread: " + getName() + " running");
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

}

and the thread.sleep is working for me.

What kind of application is yours? is it a web-app? if so, which application container did you use?

Comment: Yes it is web-app. what do you mean which stack?

Comment: app container: tomcat 7

Comment: I have inserted the same code in a tomcat7 app deployed on cloudbees. The thread 5 runs after 15s, as forced by the thread.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to set up a recurring scheduled task rather than using sleep().